# Grupo radio con funcion muestra el value="texto" al seleccionar, con checked="yes" por defecto tendría que mostrarlo tambien

Tags: javascript

tengo un grupo radio, con una funcion que muestra el valor al checkear la seleccion. Funciona bien. 
Le agregué un opción seleccionada por defecto con checked="yes". que tambien se aplicó bien.
Por lógica supuse que el texto de la opción seleccionada por defecto también debería aparecer. Al fin y al cabo esta seleccionada del mismo modo. QUisiera que suceda eso. Les dejo un archivo donde está el ejemplo

https://jsfiddle.net/hernan527/skL4e7b9/44/#&togetherjs=MPOt5duTld

El html:

```
    <span class="ef-example-1-rating" id="odontologia">
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-5" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello5" >
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-5" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-4" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello4">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-4" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-3" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello3">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-3" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-2" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello2">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-2" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <input type="radio" class="ef-example-1-rating-input" id="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-1" name="ef-example-1-rating-input-1" value="Hello1" checked="yes">
    <label for="ef-example-1-rating-input-1-1" class="ef-example-1-rating-star"></label>
    <br />
    <p id="forro" style="color:red;"></p>
    </span>
```

Esta es la funcion:

```
    $(function() {
        var $radBtn = $("#odontologia");
        $radBtn.click(function() {
            var $radChecked = $radBtn.find(':radio:checked');
            $("#forro").text('')
                .append($radChecked.val());
        });
    });
```

Gracias por su colaboracion.

Answer (score 0):

Veo todo bien, lo que creo que falta es que se ejecute tu código cuando se cargue la pagina para que muestre el texto del cheked por defecto. Bastaría con agregar tu código dentro de esta función:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
ejemplo();
});
```

Para eso debes nombrar tu función para simplemente llamarla desde aqui.

```
$(function() { var $radBtn = $("#odontologia");
$radBtn.click(function ejemplo(){ 
var $radChecked = $radBtn.find(':radio:checked'); 
$("#forro").text(''") .append($radChecked.val()); 
});
})
```

Comment: Hola, estuve revisando, seguramente es eso lo que debería hacer, pero lo intente aplicar sin exito. En el mismo html tengo otras dos funciones que utilizan $( document ).ready(function() {, e intente implemetarlo pero sin exito. Gracias .saludos

Comment: Pues tienes algún problema también ahí, te recomiendo que crees otra pregunta para solucionar eso, luego de solucionado aplica mi respuesta.

Comment: Bueno, aunque es mala practica entra todo ese codigo dentro de document.ready para probar si funciona y asi tengas idea del problema

Comment: Borre todo, solo deje el grupo radio; y nada tampoco . https://jsfiddle.net/hernan527/skL4e7b9/106/#&togetherjs=Fhg8zBDKCM . SI la nomro no funciona, ahora la deje con la linea  $( document ).ready(function() { y cerrar con
}); , Igual q sin eso. gracias

Comment: Intenta tan solo poner $("#forro").text('') .append($radChecked.val()); });

Comment: En el document.ready

Comment: No funcionó tampoco. gracias